# StackOverflowException was unhandled in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I want to move rows from `DataGridViewX1` to another form's `DataGridView` by using this code:

Button click event:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingCompleteDataGridView.DataSource = DataGridViewX1.Rows
    frmEncodeDatabase.Show()
End Sub
```

Another form's `DataGridView`'s `RowsAdd` event:

```
EncodingCompleteDataGridView.Rows.Add(frmEncode.DataGridViewX1.Rows)
```

Now the code above is where I am having problems: the StackOverflowException. (the error's description are in the image below)

http://postimg.org/image/4d91ex49j/

Comment: You're adding rows inside the `RowsAdded` event. This will fire the `RowsAdded` event which will add a new row and raise the event again and add a new row and raise the event and add a row....

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå Where should I put the code then? Should I add it on UserAddRow?

Comment: You should always manipulate the underlying data source. In this case, the data source bound to the second DGV.

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå  I forgot to note that my first DataGridView is not data-bounded. I need to know how to transfer the rows of the  first DGV to THAT DataGridView (which causes the error) that is data-bounded. Help me please?

Comment: is there code in `DataGridViewX1`'s row added or other event?  You could look at the call stack (**DEBUG -> Windows - Call Stack**) to get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: How is the 2nd grid databound? With what type of object? Can you edit your question with some sample code that shows how you are databinding?

Comment: Datagridview is data-bounded, yes...but my 2nd grid view is from an Access database which I have no code in it on how to databind. All the codes in my question is the codes on both on my gridviews.

Comment: The solution to your problem is not difficult, but without knowing more about your particular scenario we can only guess how you are populating your datagridviews. I have provided an example below on how to accomplish what you desire by using a datatable object. Please give more detail on how you are reading data from the access database and we may be able help you further.

Comment: The way how you connect database in VB.NET is how I am 'reading data from the access database' so there is no need of populating data. As I said, the second one is data-bounded. For your code below I copied the Button click event because I find the 'populating' unnecessary. The error 'InvalidCastException was unhandled' was shown in the following screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/k65b52bxn/

Comment: There hasn't been any activity on this post for over a week. Please let us know how you solved this problem or if you require further help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic example to help you in the right direction.

This example:

- Demonstrates how to combine rows from a datagridview that is not databound into a datagridview that is databound
- Assumes that both datagridviews have the same number of columns and in the same order.
- Assumes that the databound gridview is bound to a datatable.

I realize your real life example has the datagridviews on separate forms but the code is easier to follow on one form for this example.

To test this, do the following:

1) Create a new form (Form1), add 2 datagridviews (DataGridView1 and DataGridView2) and one button (Button1)

2) Replace the code on Form1 one with this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Manually add columns to the first datagridview which will not be data bound

        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column1", "Column1")
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column2", "Column2")
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column3", "Column3")

        ' Poulate both datagridviews

        PopulateDataGrid1Manually()
        PopulateDataGrid2DataBound()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PopulateDataGrid1Manually()
        ' This datagridview has data added manually without being databound

        Dim sRow(Me.DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1) As String

        For r As Int32 = 1 To 3 ' Adding 3 rows of test data
            For c As Int32 = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                sRow(c) = "data" & r.ToString
            Next

            Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(sRow)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub PopulateDataGrid2DataBound()
        ' This datagridview is databound to a datatable

        Dim dt As New DataTable

        dt.Columns.Add("Column1", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Column2", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Column3", GetType(String))

        Dim dr As DataRow

        For i As Int32 = 1 To 3 ' Adding 3 rows of test data
            dr = dt.NewRow
            dr("Column1") = "new" & i.ToString
            dr("Column2") = "new" & i.ToString
            dr("Column3") = "new" & i.ToString
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next

        Me.DataGridView2.DataSource = dt    ' Databind
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Copy rows from the first datagridview to the second datagridview that is data bound
        ' First copy the second datagridviews datasource into a new data table

        Dim dt As DataTable = CType(Me.DataGridView2.DataSource, DataTable).Copy
        Dim dr As DataRow

        ' Loop through all rows of the first datagridview and copy them into the data table

        For r As Int32 = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r).IsNewRow = False Then   ' Do not copy the new row
                dr = dt.NewRow

                ' Loop through all cells of the first datagridview and populate the data row

                For c As Int32 = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                    dr(c) = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value
                Next

                dt.Rows.Add(dr) ' Add the data row to the data table
            End If
        Next

        Me.DataGridView2.DataSource = dt    ' Rebind the second datagridview with the new table which has all the rows from both datagridviews
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: My datagridview in Form1...well, already has columns and has no data source. It has more than 10 columns. So I'm going to keep in mind the button click.

Comment: This is just an example to show you how to add rows from one datagridview to another. Your question included code showing the datasource from one datagridview being populated from another in a button_click event. If you aren't trying to populate via button click, how do you want it to function exactly? Please edit your question and provide more detail so that I or someone else can assist you better.

Comment: For the button_click I want the rows from DGV1 which is non-data bound to DGV2 which is databounded. DGV2 has a datasource and DGV1 has none. Your **Demonstrates how to combine rows from a datagridview that is not databound into a datagridview that is databound** is fine. Now I just want to see the screenshot about the error I got:  postimg.org/image/k65b52bxn

Comment: What type of object is the DataSource of the BindingSource? You can find out by setting a breakpoint on the line that gives you the error and typing this into the immediate window: ?Ctype(frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingCompleteDataGridView.DataSource, BindingSource).DataSource

Comment: `Dim dt As DataTable = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)

DataGridView2.DataSource = dt.Copy()`

It lets me copy the contents from dgv1 to dgv2.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dt As DataTable = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable) 
DataGridView2.DataSource = dt.Copy()
```

It lets me copy the contents from dgv1 to dgv2.