# InvalidCastException was unhandled in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Referring to this question: [StackOverflowException was unhandled in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640192/stackoverflowexception-was-unhandled-in-vb-net) I decided to create a new question because I have a new error.

> *Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.*

CODE (in button click event):

```
' Copy rows from the first datagridview to the second datagridview that is data bound
    ' First copy the second datagridviews datasource into a new data table

    Dim dt As DataTable = CType(frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingDataGridView.DataSource, DataTable).Copy
    Dim dr As DataRow

    ' Loop through all rows of the first datagridview and copy them into the data table

    For r As Int32 = 0 To Me.DataGridViewX1.Rows.Count - 1
        If Me.DataGridViewX1.Rows(r).IsNewRow = False Then   ' Do not copy the new row
            dr = dt.NewRow

            ' Loop through all cells of the first datagridview and populate the data row

            For c As Int32 = 0 To Me.DataGridViewX1.ColumnCount - 1
                dr(c) = Me.DataGridViewX1.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value
            Next

            dt.Rows.Add(dr) ' Add the data row to the data table
        End If
    Next

    Me.DataGridView2.DataSource = dt    ' Rebind the second datagridview with the new table which has all the rows from both datagridviews
    frmEncodeDatabase.show()
```

The error, which is in the image, is in `dt As DataTable = CType(frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingDataGridView.DataSource, DataTable).Copy` where the error is right now. How will I modify the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is self-explainable.

> "*Unabled to cast object of type **'BindingSource'** to type **'DataTable'.***"

The datassource of your datagridview is a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you need to cast to this type.

```
Dim bs As BindingSource = CType(frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingDataGridView.DataSource, BindingSource)
```

Assuming that the datasource of the bindingsource is a datatable:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = CType(bs.DataSource, DataTable)
```

If not, you'll get another cast exception, but now you how to fix it.

Comment: I have another cast exception in **dt As DataTable = CType(bs.DataSource, DataTable)** It says: "INVALIDCASTEXCEPTION: Unable to cast object of type 'Golden_Dragon_Billing_System.EncodingCompleteDataSet' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'. Error image: http://postimg.org/image/a9c5tsb93/

Comment: Do you need to see my source project? I'm SICK and TIRED of this!!

Comment: @CodingSource No I don't need to see your source project, but *you* need to read my answer *again*. I **assumed** that the datasource of your bindingsource was a datatable, it wasn't. So what is it one might wonder? If you read the *new* error message carefully you'll see that it's `DataSet`. So you need to cast it to `EncodingCompleteDataSet`. And please forgive me, but my crystal-ball got broken while predicting next weeks lotto numbers.

Comment: @CodingSource This solved your problem so please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This way people knows that the question has been solved. And, as a bonus, you gain +2 reputation and a badge.